# How can I get entitlements from my WSO2 Identity Server?

Tags: wso2, entitlements, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to use the EntitlementService operation GetEntitledAttributes against the policies in my WSO2 Identity Server.  I am expecting that if I make this call passing in only a subject_id,(role name,) that I should get back the resources and actions applicable to that role, but I get no matches at all.  In the sample provided below, I am expecting to get back the resource "EchoService" and the action "read".  I am using WSO2 IS 4.1.0 with the default policy and attribute finders.  Can someone tell me what I need to do to get entitlements from my WSO2 Identity Server?

Thank you,

Katrina

This is the request:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
     <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soapenv:Body>
         <getEntitledAttributes xmlns="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd"                xmlns:ns2="http://dto.entitlement.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
           <subjectName>Manager</subjectName>
           <resourceName/>
           <subjectId/>
           <action/>
          <enableChildSearch>true</enableChildSearch>
        </getEntitledAttributes>
       </soapenv:Body>
      </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is one of the policies which should be evaluated:

```
    <Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"      PolicyId="EchoServicePolicy"      RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
<Target>
      <AnyOf>
         <AllOf>
            <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Manager</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject"                 DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
            </Match>
         </AllOf>
      </AnyOf>
   </Target>
   <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule-1">
      <Target>
         <AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
               <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">EcoService</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource"              DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
               </Match>
            </AllOf>
         </AnyOf>
         <AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
               <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action"              DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
               </Match>
            </AllOf>
         </AnyOf>
      </Target>
   </Rule>
   <Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="Rule-2">
      <Target>
         <AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
               <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">EcoService</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource"                DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
               </Match>
            </AllOf>
         </AnyOf>
         <AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
               <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">write</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action"                DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
               </Match>
            </AllOf>
         </AnyOf>
      </Target>
   </Rule>
</Policy>
```

Answer (score 0):

This method allows applications to check what are the resources that uses can access according to the XACML PDP in dynamic manner.According to the XACML core specification, It only talks about a PDP that can provide authorization result of boolean values (Basically permit, deny, not applicable, indeterminate results and some additional data using advice and obligations). Basically from the PDP, application (PEP) can ask something like “is user authorized to do this” ?   And application (PEP) can not ask a question like "what are the allowed resources and actions for given user?"  This method provides that capability. You can find more details from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/11/22/can-xacml-support-to-retrieve-allowed-permissions-for-given-subject/) and there also a sample that you can try